# captcha not rendering in vue.js laravel 5.6.7

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5

I am trying to incorporate recaptcha in vue.js, I am also using Laravel 5.6.7

**Vue Package for Captcha**

https://github.com/DanSnow/vue-recaptcha#install

**Blade**

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <login></login>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
import VueRecaptcha from 'vue-recaptcha';
Vue.use(VueRecaptcha);

Vue.component('login', require('./components/login.vue'));
```

**Login Component in vue.js**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My site key">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Problem**

I placed the div for captcha but it renders nothing. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](https://github.com/DanSnow/vue-recaptcha#install), VueRecaptcha was imported and added to as component.

```
import VueRecaptcha from 'vue-recaptcha';
export default {
    ...
    components: { VueRecaptcha }
};
```

In the template it stated to use the `vue-recaptcha` tag.

```
<vue-recaptcha sitekey="Your key here">
    <button>Click me</button>
</vue-recaptcha>
```

Comment: Where to write this `export default {` ? inside the component or inside app.js?

Comment: Basically, you can write it in your Vue instance or `Vue.component('vue-recaptcha', VueRecaptcha);`

Comment: Or you can try to `Vue.use(VueRecaptcha);` and use `vue-recaptcha` tag if it do works.

Comment: can u suggest here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364689/captcha-form-validation-required-error-message-in-vue-recaptcha